# Using SAMPLE in ClickHouse seems to read all rows and more bytes. Is this expected or due to sub-optimal table definition?

Tags: performance, sample, clickhouse

I'm hoping to trade accuracy for speed by using SAMPLE. While some queries do run faster, the query_log shows that all rows are being read and more bytes are read than when not using SAMPLE. I thought SAMPLE would result in fewer row reads.

### My questions:

1. Should using SAMPLE result in more rows and bytes being read?
2. Is this increased reading due to a sub-optimal table definition that can be corrected?

I'm using ClickHouse version 20.5.3 revision 54435.

#### Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE default.table_one
(
  `datestamp` Date,
  `timestamp` UInt64,
  `sample_hash` UInt64,
  `value` UInt32,
  ...
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY date_stamp
ORDER BY (datestamp, timestamp, sample_hash)
SAMPLE BY sample_hash
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

#### Query without SAMPLE

```
SELECT
  avg(value)
FROM default.table_one;

query_duration_ms: 166
rows_read: 100,000,000
read_bytes: 800,000,000
```

#### Query with SAMPLE

```
SELECT
  avg(value)
FROM default.table_one
SAMPLE 0.1;

query_duration_ms: 358
rows_read: 100,000,000
read_bytes: 1,600,000,000
```

Comment: see related discussion [ClickHouse Google Group: More information on SAMPLE](https://groups.google.com/g/clickhouse/c/ad7YEo4oLNQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Because CH needs to read one more column sample_hash.

Long answer: Sampling is hard. It is useful if you have 100 billions rows per day and 400 servers. It helps with groupbys a lot. It's not helpful in filtering because in your case it does not work along with primary index.
Yandex has designed sampling for themselves. They have enabled forced partitioningkeys/primarykeys usage (force_index_by_date/force_primary_key). So queries like yours are impossible in their system and thus sampling helps them even in disk reading.

That's why I don't use Sampling in my systems.

But

> ORDER BY (datestamp, timestamp, sample_hash)

Also such `ORDER BY` is not useful at all. This whole table is misdesign.
No sense to put  `(datestamp` in the index prefix because the table is partitioned by `datestamp` so each partition has only ONE `datestamp` value.

`timestamp` in the index prefix is an even bigger issue because it's very unwise to put a highly cardinal column in the beginning of a primary index.

So. I can create a synthetic example and show how `sampling` works. But does it have any sense?

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
( timestamp UInt64,
  transaction_id UInt64,
  banner_id UInt16,
  value UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(toDateTime(timestamp))
ORDER BY (banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)),  cityHash64(transaction_id))
SAMPLE BY cityHash64(transaction_id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192


insert into table_one select 1602809234+intDiv(number,100000), number, number%991, toUInt32(rand())
from numbers(10000000000);



select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
group by banner_id format Null;

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 11.490 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 60.00 GB (870.30 million rows/s., 5.22 GB/s.)

select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
group by banner_id format Null;

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.316 sec. Processed 452.67 million rows, 6.34 GB (343.85 million rows/s., 4.81 GB/s.)



select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
WHERE banner_id = 42
group by banner_id format Null;

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.020 sec. Processed 10.30 million rows, 61.78 MB (514.37 million rows/s., 3.09 GB/s.)

select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
WHERE banner_id = 42
group by banner_id format Null;

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.008 sec. Processed 696.32 thousand rows, 9.75 MB (92.49 million rows/s., 1.29 GB/s.)




select banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)) hr, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
group by banner_id, hr format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 36.660 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 140.00 GB (272.77 million rows/s., 3.82 GB/s.)

select banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)) hr, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
group by banner_id, hr format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 3.741 sec. Processed 452.67 million rows, 9.96 GB (121.00 million rows/s., 2.66 GB/s.)




select count()
from table_one 
where value = 666 format Null;
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 6.056 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 40.00 GB (1.65 billion rows/s., 6.61 GB/s.)

select count()
from table_one  SAMPLE 0.01
where value = 666 format Null;
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.214 sec. Processed 452.67 million rows, 5.43 GB (372.88 million rows/s., 4.47 GB/s.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard part:
Here is an example how a high cardinality column in the primary index impacts.
**The same table, the same data** but instead of

`ORDER BY (banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)),  cityHash64(transaction_id))`

I used

`ORDER BY (banner_id, timestamp, cityHash64(transaction_id))`

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
( timestamp UInt64,
  transaction_id UInt64,
  banner_id UInt16,
  value UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(toDateTime(timestamp))
ORDER BY (banner_id, timestamp, cityHash64(transaction_id))
SAMPLE BY cityHash64(transaction_id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192

insert into table_one select 1602809234+intDiv(number,100000), number, number%991, toUInt32(rand())
from numbers(10000000000);



select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
group by banner_id format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 11.196 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 60.00 GB (893.15 million rows/s., 5.36 GB/s.)

select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
group by banner_id format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 24.378 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 140.00 GB (410.21 million rows/s., 5.74 GB/s.)



select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
WHERE banner_id = 42
group by banner_id format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.022 sec. Processed 10.27 million rows, 61.64 MB (459.28 million rows/s., 2.76 GB/s.)

select banner_id, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
WHERE banner_id = 42
group by banner_id format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.037 sec. Processed 10.27 million rows, 143.82 MB (275.16 million rows/s., 3.85 GB/s.)



select banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)) hr, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one 
group by banner_id, hr format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 21.663 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 140.00 GB (461.62 million rows/s., 6.46 GB/s.)


select banner_id, toStartOfHour(toDateTime(timestamp)) hr, sum(value), count(value), max(value)
from table_one SAMPLE 0.01
group by banner_id, hr format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 26.697 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 220.00 GB (374.57 million rows/s., 8.24 GB/s.)



select count()
from table_one 
where value = 666 format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 7.679 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 40.00 GB (1.30 billion rows/s., 5.21 GB/s.)

select count()
from table_one  SAMPLE 0.01
where value = 666 format Null;
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 21.668 sec. Processed 10.00 billion rows, 120.00 GB (461.51 million rows/s., 5.54 GB/s.)
```

High cardinal column timestamp makes to impossible use a range seeks in index for `cityHash64(transaction_id))`. CH reads every `mark` for 0.01 piece.
This is the expected behavior and the same is true for any database or any sorted list.

Now CH reads all rows with .001 sampling and without.